# How do I solve MediaWiki 1.35.0 installation Error 1044

Tags: debian, mediawiki

When I tried to install WikiMedia 1.35.0 on Debian I got this error message (Error 1044). I don't know how to solve this problem.

I used this manual: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Running_MediaWiki_on_Debian_or_Ubuntu#Step-By-Step

Here is the errormessage

```
13ee4114e7ac90bbe93955a6] /mediawiki/mw-config/index.php?page=Install Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError from line 1699 of /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php: A database query error has occurred. Did you forget to run your application's database schema updater after upgrading?

Error 1044: Access denied for user 'HKsqldude'@'localhost' to database 'hk_wiki' (localhost)
Function: MysqlInstaller::setupDatabase
Query: CREATE DATABASE `hk_wiki`CHARACTER SET utf8
Backtrace:

#0 /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1683): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->getQueryException(string, integer, string, string)
#1 /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1658): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->getQueryExceptionAndLog(string, integer, string, string)
#2 /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1227): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->reportQueryError(string, integer, string, string, boolean)
#3 /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/installer/MysqlInstaller.php(450): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query(string, string)
#4 /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/installer/Installer.php(1654): MysqlInstaller->setupDatabase(MysqlInstaller)
#5 /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/installer/WebInstallerInstall.php(44): Installer->performInstallation(array, array)
#6 /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/installer/WebInstaller.php(269): WebInstallerInstall->execute()
#7 /var/lib/mediawiki/mw-config/index.php(82): WebInstaller->execute(array)
#8 /var/lib/mediawiki/mw-config/index.php(40): wfInstallerMain()
#9 {main}
```

Comment: Re-read the "MySQL configuration" section of that manual. You probably made some mistake related to creating or using the MySQL user account.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly, after I recreated the sql-Database

Answer (score 0):

You should try run the [update script](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Update.php) which will automatically create the necessary database tables that this extension needs.

Usually something like this: (from your root folder):

```
php maintenance/update.php
```